# Sharing image to social media using framework

Tags: ios, swift

I'm going to share an edited image to social image. Currently, I'm using the 0.png to treat as the output image.

Now, how can I replace 0.png to the edited image and share it?

```
import UIKit
import Social

class EditController: UIViewController {
var image:UIImage?
var index:Int?

@IBOutlet weak var photo: UIImageView!

let context = CIContext(options: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.photo.image = self.image
}

@IBAction func applyFilter(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("applyFilter")
    let beginImage = CIImage(image: self.image!)

    let randomColor = [kCIInputAngleKey: (Double(arc4random_uniform(314)) / 100)]
    let filteredImage = beginImage!.imageByApplyingFilter("CIHueAdjust", withInputParameters: randomColor)
    let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage, fromRect: filteredImage.extent)
    self.image = UIImage(CGImage: renderedImage)
    self.photo.image = self.image
}

@IBAction func shareToFacebook(sender: AnyObject) {
    let shareToFacebook : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    shareToFacebook.setInitialText("Hello I Posted Using Swift And Social Framework")
    shareToFacebook.addImage(UIImage(named: "0.png"))
    self.presentViewController(shareToFacebook, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: Update self.image Object.

Comment: I fixed it by replacing UIImage(named: "0.png") to self.image. THX.

Answer (score 0):

in swift
just create a button that has SLComposeViewController method
get any random picture in project supported files like "32.png" :

```
 @IBAction func shareToTwitter() {
        var shareToTwitter : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
        shareToTwitter.setInitialText("Hello World")
        shareToTwitter.addImage(UIImage(named: "32.png"))
        self.presentViewController(shareToTwitter, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

credit:

- [IPhoneDevTips™](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a89c67TIh10)

more tutorials:

- [www.raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/21558/beginning-twitter-tutorial-updated-for-ios-6)
- [www.hackingwithswift.com](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/3/3/twitter-and-facebook-slcomposeviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the OP in the comments under their question:

> I fixed it by replacing `UIImage(named: "0.png")` to `self.image`.